# Appium Doctor: why it claims xcode not install while I installed xcode indeed?

Tags: xcode, appium, appium-ios

Here is my screenshot from mac app store:

[image]

you can see I install xcode clearly.

But when I run appium-doctor:

```
➜  ~ appium-doctor
info AppiumDoctor Appium Doctor v.1.13.0
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies starting ###
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: /usr/local/bin/node
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Node version is 13.5.0
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ Xcode is NOT installed!
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode Command Line Tools are installed in: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ DevToolsSecurity is enabled.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Authorization DB is set up properly.
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Carthage was found at: /usr/local/bin/carthage. Installed version is: 0.34.0
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ HOME is set to: /Users/zhengxiangshen
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ ANDROID_HOME is NOT set!
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ JAVA_HOME is NOT set!
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ adb could not be found because ANDROID_HOME is NOT set!
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ android could not be found because ANDROID_HOME is NOT set!
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ emulator could not be found because ANDROID_HOME is NOT set!
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ Bin directory for $JAVA_HOME is not set
```

It claims `WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ Xcode is NOT installed!`, so I get confused.

Could anyone give me some suggestions about that? Is Xcode not installed correctly? How could I cover this issue?

Update:
I checked, and XCode is in my Application folder:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It picks the `Xcode` from the `Applications` folder. So you need to move the `Xcode` to the `Applications` folder first and then you can run this command.